# compiling *.C and *.S sources from same directory 'make'

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have been working with a project that only compiles C sources but I've found I need some assembler too, I'm reticent to inline the asm code in a C file as GCC may not interpret it correctly.

My predecesor created the makefile for the project (apologies, it's fairly long):

```
# Compiler and options
CC          := sparc-rtems-gcc

# The application software binary
TARGET      := icu_asw

# Source and build directories
SRCDIR      := src
BUILDDIR    := obj
TARGETDIR   := bin
HDSWROOT    := ../../hdsw
BSWTOOLS    := ../../bsw/sw/tools
SRCEXT      := c
DEPEXT      := d
OBJEXT      := o
MRAMEXT     := img.elf

# Flags, libraries and includes
CFLAGS      := -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -g
LIBDRV      := $(HDSWROOT)/lib/libdrv.a 
INCFLAGS    := -I$(HDSWROOT)/include -I$(HDSWROOT)/osal/rtems

# Debug flags
DEBUGFLAGS = -DLOGERROR=1 -DLOGWARN=1 -DLOGDEBUG=1 -DLOGINFO=1 -DMAKECHECKS=1
NODEBUGFLAGS = -DLOGERROR=1 -DLOGWARN=0 -DLOGDEBUG=0 -DLOGINFO=0 -DMAKECHECKS=1

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Build instructions
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
SOURCES     := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name *.$(SRCEXT))
OBJECTS     := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.$(OBJEXT)))

# Default make
all: $(TARGET)

# Remake
remake: cleaner all

# Clean only objects
clean:
    @$(RM) -rf $(BUILDDIR)

# Full clean (objects and binaries)
cleaner: clean
    @$(RM) -rf $(TARGETDIR)

# Pull in dependency info for *existing* .o files
-include $(OBJECTS:.$(OBJEXT)=.$(DEPEXT))

# Link (uses an order-only prerequisite for the directories so that they
# don't affect the use of the $^)
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) | directories
    $(CC) -o $(TARGETDIR)/$(TARGET) $^ $(LIBDRV)

# Make the build and target directories
directories:
    @mkdir -p $(TARGETDIR)
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)

# Compile
$(BUILDDIR)/%.$(OBJEXT): $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCFLAGS) $(NODEBUGFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCDEP) -MM $(SRCDIR)/$*.$(SRCEXT) > $(BUILDDIR)/$*.$(DEPEXT)
    @cp -f $(BUILDDIR)/$*.$(DEPEXT) $(BUILDDIR)/$*.$(DEPEXT).tmp
    @sed -e 's|.*:|$(BUILDDIR)/$*.$(OBJEXT):|' < $(BUILDDIR)/$*.$(DEPEXT).tmp > $(BUILDDIR)/$*.$(DEPEXT)
    @sed -e 's/.*://' -e 's/\\$$//' < $(BUILDDIR)/$*.$(DEPEXT).tmp | fmt -1 | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/$$/:/' >> $(BUILDDIR)/$*.$(DEPEXT)
    @rm -f $(BUILDDIR)/$*.$(DEPEXT).tmp

# Non-File Targets
.PHONY: all remake clean cleaner
```

I want to also bring in and compile two .S files, so, I edited the following line

```
SOURCES     := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name *.$(SRCEXT) -or -name *.$(ASMEXT))
```

To bring in the .S files, then I edited the OBJECTS to also include the ASM sources ("*.S")

```
OBJECTS     := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.$(OBJEXT)),$(SOURCES:.$(ASMEXT)=.$(OBJEXT)))
```

But when recompiling with 'make all' I'm getting:

```
$ make all
make: *** No rule to make target `obj/asi_access.S', needed by `icu_asw'.  Stop.
```

I don't suppose someone could spot where I am going wrong? I think I have not correctly added to the OBJECTS line!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The expression `$(var:.ext1=.ext2)` *does not* filter by `.ext1`, i.e.

```makefile
$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.$(OBJEXT)) $(SOURCES:.$(ASMEXT)=.$(OBJEXT))
```

gives for a test source list the following result

```
a.o b.o c.S a.c b.c c.o
```

I.e. you duplicated your files and you have source files in the `OBJECTS` definition.

The following would be a correct approach:

```makefile
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%, \
             $(patsubst %.$(SRCEXT),%.$(OBJEXT), \
               $(patsubst %.$(ASMEXT),%.$(OBJEXT),$(SOURCES)) \
             ) \
           )
```

---

**UPDATE:** you should consider to use 2 separate object lists, so that you can apply different rules for them, e.g.

```makefile
SOURCES_C   := $(filter %.$(SRCEXT),$(SOURCES))
OBJECTS_C   := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES_C:%.$(SRCEXT)=%.$(OBJEXT)))
SOURCES_ASM := $(filter %.$(ASMEXT),$(SOURCES))
OBJECTS_ASM := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES_ASM:%.$(ASMEXT)=%.$(OBJEXT)))

$(OBJECTS_C): $(BUILDDIR)/%.$(OBJEXT): $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
    .... C compiler recipe ....

$(OBJECTS_ASM): $(BUILDDIR)/%.$(OBJEXT): $(SRCDIR)/%.$(ASMEXT)
    .... assembler recipe ....

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS_C) $(OBJECTS_ASM) | directories
```

Comment: Hmm, now I get: 
make: *** No rule to make target `obj/asi_access.', needed by `icu_asw'.  Stop.

Comment: I would suggest to add `$(info OBJECTS '$(OBJECTS)')` to the makefile so that you can see what the actual variable contents are. That is easier than guessing in the dark what might be wrong... You probably have a variable name typo in the patsubst, i.e.  `asi_access.S` gets replaced with `asi_access.`

Comment: Ah ok, so it seems that every file extension is missing. OBJECTS 'obj/asi_access. obj/copy_nocache. .... etc.
edit: Just seen your update so will explore further. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I typed `$(OBJECT)` instead of `$(OBJEXT)` :-/ I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I am getting further but I think now I also have to edit: 
-include $(OBJECTS:.$(OBJEXT)=.$(DEPEXT)) for OBJECTS_C and OBJECTS_ASM. Can I have both on the same line? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189142/discussion-between-mr-alex-nok-and-stefan-becker).

Comment: IMO the easiest thing is to use `$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SOURCES))` which will strip off the suffix of all files, regardless of what it is, then add on a `.o`.  Second, the only reason you need to separate out different lists is because you're trying to use static pattern rules.  If you just stick with pattern rules, as in the original makefile, then you don't need to create two lists.  Just add a new pattern rule for .S files and you're done.